# Minimum Packages needed to get started, Android SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

There's a limit to which I can download Packages.

So can anyone explain that what will be the essential components that must be downloaded in order to get started with sdk or to just make it work fine.

I am searching for the minimal components to be downloaded.

When I launch SDK manager it shows up a list showing various packages,
Very First Android 6.0 API contains lot's of other packages within, So of them which Packages are must to install.

The packages that has been installed are,
[image]

The thing that's confusing me, is this list of packages:
[image]

So Question,
Which are mandatory to get started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the Android SDK does not include everything you need to start developing. The SDK separates tools, platforms, and other components into packages you can download as needed using the Android SDK Manager. So before you can start, there are a few packages you should add to your Android SDK.

> As a minimum when setting up the Android SDK, you should download the
>   latest tools and Android platform:

Open the Tools directory and select:

1. **Android SDK Tools**
2. **Android SDK Platform-tools**
3. **Android SDK Build-tools (highest version)**

Open the first Android X.X folder (the latest version) and select:

**`SDK Platform A system image for the emulator`**, such as 
**ARM EABI v7a System Image**

For more details you should read ***official documents*** **[Adding SDK Packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)** .I hope it will helps you .

Comment: In most cases **Intel x86 System Image** is preferred as the ARM architecture doesn't have to be emulated. It is about 10x times faster.

Answer (score 7):

Here list of packages you must install for the proper functioning.

Latest version of :

- **Android SDK Tools**
- **Android SDK Platform-tools**
- **Android SDK Build-tools**

Based on your application you can what all API needed.

Important things download from API(XX) -(Android X.X) packages are.

- **SDK Platform**
- if you are testing application **using emulator then download the System Image** , such as **ARM EABI v7a System Image, Intel x86 Atom System Image** (no need to download System Image for TV and Wear).

For more detailed explanation [Adding SDK Packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)