# Installing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have download `android studio` latest (1.12 GB). And now installing. But it takes lot of time because I have a slow internet connection. Can any one please suggest me the necessary tools in SDK manager to install?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759125/minimum-packages-needed-to-get-started-android-sdk/34759248#34759248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1- Get the latest SDK tools**

As a minimum when setting up the Android SDK, you should download the latest tools and Android platform:
Open the Tools directory and select:

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools (highest version)

Open the first Android X.X folder (the latest version) and select:

**SDK Platform**

A system image for the emulator, such as

**ARM EABI v7a System Image**

**2- Get the support library for additional APIs**

- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library

Answer (score 0):

you must need to install all the tools folder and the extras along with the minimum api that you want to work on.

Comment: i am just creating a Hello World Application

Comment: It needs to get install , if you want to run the app in the emulator or or in your device

Comment: Get the detailed procedure,[here](http://www.androidperitia.com/install_androidstudio/)