# What is the minimum packages required to create virtual device in android studio

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm running android studio from usb. (laptop has small hardrive 15g) so I decided to run studio from usb. But I'm having problems creating a virtual device. I've downloaded "Android SDK tools, Android platform tools, and build tools" from tools. "sdk platform, google api atom 86_64" from API 25. "sdk platform, arm eabi v7 system image, google api, sources" from API 22. Finally, "android support repos" and "google repos"... is this the bare minimum? if I wanted to develop an app for Android 5.1.1 (api 22)
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum Packages needed to get started, Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759125/minimum-packages-needed-to-get-started-android-sdk)

Comment: here is a solution on how to make it run from a usb drive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149226/portable-android-studio